# Facebook signup-> get user fb info->authenticate with my app-> if user exists in database then login otherwise create account

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I got a small problem with facebook signup. After I logged in to facebook then I am fetching user facebook data and populate in our app. Then user creates username and password then create an account. If he tries to signup with same facebook details I have to directly log in this user. I am using Parse database. I dont know how to fetch [pfuser currentUser] manually?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with folowing function :

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) 
         {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
           } 
         else if (user.isNew) {
            yourUser = (PFYourUserClass*) user;
            [self getDetailsFromFacebook]; // get your rest details from facebook
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            yourUser = (PFYourUserClass*) user;
            // and load rest of data

        }
    }];
```

hope it helps ;)
also you can check [Parse Facebook Login & SignUP](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-signup/iOS)

Comment: `user.isNew` was the critical thing to check, didn't know this existed before